# Virtualization: See OSX files in Bootcamp VM

Tags: windows, macos, virtualization, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

Seems like this should be easy enough, but I have yet to find a simple solution.

I'm using VMWare Fusion to access my Bootcamp partition through a VM on my OSX side. I'm trying to access my OSX files inside of the Bootcamp partition, but I'm not able to see the OSX partition anymore.

Is it possible to read and/or write files in the OSX partition from within a Bootcamp VM? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8267/accessing-files-from-mac-os-x-in-vmware-fusion), this can be achieved using a shared folder:

> When I need to access files that are on the Mac OS X side from within Windows, I **go the VM preferences** and **enable each folder I want to share** (you can share multiple folders form different locations). All shared folders will then be **shown on the Z:\ drive** in Windows.